# Import camera animation from Maya 2014

Tags: export, camera, import

There's a bunch of import/export formats common to both Blender and Maya, but which of them support animation? FBX is supposed to, but for now our addon doesn't support that yet.

Specifically, I need to get animated cameras from a Maya scene into Blender.

One way would be to export a file for each frame (which would need markers and attaching cameras to them to make each frame's camera the active one for that frame) but that wouldn't work with motion blur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **DAE_FBX exporter** works, just select the cameras and use *File > Export Selection > (channel box) DAE_FBX Export*. The usual `y-up` versus `z-up` happen, but otherwise it's fine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCOLLADA](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/OpenCOLLADA) supports animated cameras and the SDK includes a Maya plug-in. Setting the active camera might need to be redone manually.

Comment: It seems to be only compatible with Maya 2008 to 2010, I'm using 2014

Comment: The separate plug-in for OpenCollada format works with Maya versions 2013 and below. Maya 2014 and forward comes with OpenCollada built into the .fbx exporter. Make sure to turn on fbxmaya on in your plug-in manager and choose the dae_fbx export option PeterT mentioned above.

Comment: This method works for cameras but doesn't work for animation on objects or characters. For that you'll need to use a .mmd and a saved .obj of your object to transfer to Blender. You can download the script here: http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/script/maya-to-houdini-particles-mdd-obj-exporter